# Deletion of managed package

Tags: managed-package, app

I have uploaded a managed package in partner org for testing and have made two versions of it one is deprecate and other is undeprecate BUT now i want to delete this managed package from my development org because salesforce only one managed paackage. 
How can i delete the managed package?

Comment: you have created managed package or you have installed managed package ?

Comment: i have created and for testing i have installed it on other org

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setup -> Create -> Packages
Then, click on the name of the package, at top you will see delete button just click it and you can delete the package.

Comment: I have tried this but it gives this error
"This Package cannot be deleted because it has the following uploaded versions"
Version Number Version Name
1.0 Winter 2016
1.0 (Beta 2)         Winter 2016
1.0 (Beta 1)         Winter 2016